# Can AWK call an external program during processing?

Tags: awk, gawk, nawk

Is it possible for AWK to call an external program during processing - passing it arguments and getting information returned - only to continue processing after the execution of the external program is complete ?

Answer (score 2):

yes, there are two ways to call external commands, `system()` and `getline`. you can get the returned text by using `getline`, `system()` will give you the return code of the external cmd. see this example:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{"wc -l /etc/passwd"|getline var; print var}' 
20 /etc/passwd
```

this example called the external cmd `wc -l /etc/passwd`, and assigned the returned value to awk variable: `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is an example:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  "date +%Y" | getline
  print "The year is "$0
}'
```

output:

> The year is 2014

Answer (score 0):

The `system` function can call an external command but only returns the exit code. You will have to redirect the output of the program you are calling and then read in that file.

```
retcode = system("command > file.out")
file="file.out"; 
while(( getline line < file ) > 0 ) {
    print line
}
```